# uGet looks like a linux application.How it runs on Windows?

Tags: linux, compatibility

https://ugetdm.com/
This is the app's website.The app's interface looks 100% like a linux application.It is a linux application converted to a Windows one?The app was mainly developed for linux Or it is just a windows application with Linux interface?If it is a linux app, how they converted it to a windows one?

[Interface Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfDzF.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uGet is written using a multi-platform toolkit called [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/).
GTK determines how the application looks. It is widely used among Linux applications and I guess that's where your confusion comes from. There are a lot of applications on Windows using GTK but the native solution is used more often.

Comment: GTK is only for designing Graphical user interfaces?

Comment: It is also the implementation. It's goal is to make making GUIs simply and make coherent GUIs on all platforms.